# PySpark Joining on Dates When Some Don't Exist

Tags: pyspark

I have two datasets I want to join. DF1 contains a row for each user and for each date. DF2 only contains some users and some dates.

DF1

| User_ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/22 |
| 1 | 1/2/22 |
| 1 | 1/3/22 |
| 2 | 1/1/22 |
| 2 | 1/2/22 |
| 2 | 1/3/22 |

and DF2

| User_ID | Transaction_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/22 |
| 1 | 1/3/22 |

I'm looking to join these two so as to keep every date for every user and have a null transaction date where one doesn't exist. Ideally, I'd then forward fill transaction date per user so that the end result of this join would be

| User_ID | Date | Transaction_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/22 | 1/1/22 |
| 1 | 1/2/22 | 1/1/22 |
| 1 | 1/3/22 | 1/3/22 |
| 2 | 1/1/22 | null |
| 2 | 1/2/22 | null |
| 2 | 1/3/22 | null |

I've tried to join a few different ways including

`df1 = df1.join(df2, on=[(df1.User_ID==df2.User_ID) & ((df1.Date==df2.Transaction_Date) | (df2.Transaction_Date.isNull()))`

Unfortunately, everything I've tried will drop user2, who doesn't have a transaction, and will also drop all of the dates that don't align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use `outer join` instead of normal `inner join`. You can try this:

```
df1 = df1\
   .join(df2, (df1.User_ID==df2.User_ID) & (df1.Date == df2.Transaction_Date), how='outer')\
   .select([df1.User_ID, df1.Date, df2.Transaction_Date])\
   .sort(df1.User_ID.asc(), df1.Date.asc())
df1.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this help.